docker-compose not reading from my .env file
I have a spring boot application that I have got working in a docker container and now I am trying to move some hard-coded values out of my application.properties. I know these questions get asked a lot but after reading many questions and answers I haven't been able to resolve my errors.
My application.properties has this
spring.config.import=optional:file:.env[.properties]
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
api.key=${API_KEY}

The springboot part of my docker-compose is like this
version: '3.8'

services:
  spring-boot:
    image: imagename
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
      - "5005:5005"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
      API_KEY: ${API_KEY}
    depends_on:
      - mysql

And then my .env file in the same directory as my docker-compose
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=username
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
API_KEY=apikey

When I hardcode the values into the docker-compose the container runs fine. When I run the application locally it runs fine. I had the environment variables as different names and that made no difference.
I am getting a lot of errors but this is at the top
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2024-07-02 16:01:07 
2024-07-02 16:01:07 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

I have tried adding in a env_file option but that doesn't change anything as the env_file option only passes those variables to the containers and not the Docker Compose file.
I would appreciate any help on this as I am quite stuck, thanks!

If you set spring.datasource.url to localhost, the Java application container tries to connect to itself, not the database container.  Also see Docker Compose + Spring Boot + Postgres connection.  Spring itself knows to do the environment variable substitution you show, so you don't need to put it explicitly in the application.properties file you're building into your jar file.

@DavidMaze Thanks for your reply! I am a bit confused as to what I should change localhost to. In that link they are setting it to db, which did not build for me.

Please show us the docker compose information for the mysql service. My guess is you should be using jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/db_name as the datasource URL. The service name should be used as the database host name. You can remove the URL from the .env file as it can probably be configured using just the variables in the mysql service definition.

Setting it to mysql worked thank you!
